# how to execute a string as a line of code in lua

Tags: lua, execution, opencomputers

I made myself a drone os in the minecraft mod Opencomputers, but I want to be able to make it run any line of code once recieved from the network card. I've tried everything I found here but none of it works, or atleast I haven't done it the right way. Can someone give me an example of something that will run a string as code?

This is one of the things I've tried (message is a string)

`os.execute(message)`

Is there a way to convert the string to just, not a string so I can at least see if os.execute will work how i want it to?

Comment: It can be incredibly frustrating to try many different solutions and none of them work, but we still need to see at least one coding attempt you've made. Lua has a built-in function that does what you're asking for, but there are various reasons why it might not work, so it's very important that we see something you've tried.

Comment: right, sorry forgot that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring

> To load and run a given string, use the idiom
>
> ```
>  assert(loadstring(s))()
> ```

Comment: i tried this, it yelled "attempt to call global 'loadstring' (a nil value)", is there a way i can make it not yell that?

Comment: if it is using a newer Lua version try `load` instead

Comment: reading the Lua manual helps ;)

Comment: i've been trying to read the lua manual but there's so much versions of it that pop up and im just like aaaaa